# Como consumir un WebService con SD de Genexus Evo 3

Tags: android, genexus

Alguien me podría ayudar en como consumir un WebService desde Genexus Evo 3 utilizando SmartDevices Generador.

Logro importar el wsdl, pero al tratar de consumir el método por medio de &ws.execute(in:parm1,out:parm2) me da el siguiente error

> error: Non-static method or property can't be interpreted by devices:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para lograr eso tienes que poner al SDPanel con [Connectivity Support](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?20911) : **Offline**, ó, resolver la llamada al web service en un Procedure y desde tu SDPanel llamar a ese Procedure